How can patients afford expensive surgeries but not lawsuits in the U.S. medical system in "Dr. Death"?
In the TV show Dr. Death, there are two facts mentioned that seem to be contradicting each other:

As a neurosurgeon, Duntsch claims he could get millions of dollars for the hospital he works for; I assume these millions of dollars come from the patients he operates on.
All of Duntsch's patients turn out to be too poor to afford the legal fee that comes with suing Duntsch or the hospital he works for after they suffer from his poor professionalism.

How do these two statements hold up logically?
The patients have enough money (millions of dollars every year) to pay for expensive operations yet are too poor to sue him or the hospital he works for. What am I missing here?

Health Insurance
The majority of the cost of medical treatment in the USA is paid for by medical insurance, either private schemes like many employers pay for their employees, or the publicly subsidised schemes like Obamacare (the Affordable Care Act), Medicare or Medicaid.
If I needed surgery, my insurance may pay for some or most of it. However that doesn't mean that I could afford to take the hospital to court. In-fact, because I probably would be forced to pay some of the cost of the treatment myself (a copay or deductable), I would have even less money available to pay for a lawyer.

Although I assume the insurance could take the hospital to court, for services not (or badly) rendered. Additionally, there are lawyers who work on a success-only payment base (if I can believe the movie Philadelphia). One would likely find a lawyer for a case where malpractice is obvious, partly because there is so much money to extract from a hospital.

Indeed.  But an insurance company has a different calculation than a patient.  But the main point here is that its not a contradiction for someone to be able to receive expensive treatment but not be in an immediate position to sue.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica There are absolutely personal injury lawyers who take on cases on a contingent basis. They will typically only take cases with a high likelihood of success, however. The almost guaranteed fact malpractice insurance is going to be funding and coordinating the defense has a significant impact on the chances of winning.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  One must also keep in mind that a lot of the patients who would fall into this category don't know what documentary evidence they need to take to a lawyer, don't really know much about how the legal system works, and/or will just assume that nobody will help them because that's what they've been told. You'd be amazed how many people don't even bother to seek treatment for things because they assume it will be too expensive and that insurance and/or charities won't help them.

"One would likely find a lawyer for a case where malpractice is obvious" - Yes, but would the victim of botched brain-surgery be in a position to feasibly seek one out?

@aroth Their spouse or family who would have to take care of them would be incentivized to do so in order to seek funds to hire a caretaker. If they died, the person's executor on behalf of the estate could bring an action and that would seek to replace their lost income for their spouse and children, among other things.

Is this even that American? I'm Canadian. Medicare would gladly pay for a surgery for me but the cost to sue a negligent hospital is prohibitive.
